# How to have an ouput without symbols and quotations etc. in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this particular code when the input[0] = "status", I want the output to remove the symbols "" [] and , but I can't seem to find the solution, I've tried using each but I think what I'm doing is wrong, and I'm new to Ruby please help. Thanks!

```
class Main
  puts "Welcome to the automated Parking Lot"
  start = true
  parking_lot = []
  allocated_slot = 0
  slot_number = 0
  plate_number = ""
  color = ""
  x = ""
  while (start == true) do
    parking = Array.new
    input = gets.split(' ')
    case input[0]
    when input[0] = "create_parking_lot"
      parking_lot.clear
      allocated_slot = input[1]
      puts "Created a parking lot with #{allocated_slot} slots."
    when input[0] = "park"
      plate_number = input[1]
      color = input[2]
      if parking_lot.length < allocated_slot.to_i
        slot_number = slot_number + 1
          parking = [slot_number, input[1], input[2]]
          parking_lot.push(parking)
          parking_lot.sort!
          puts "Allocated slot number: #{slot_number}"
      else
        puts "Sorry, parking lot is full"
      end
    when input[0] = "leave"
        slot_number = input[1].to_i
        puts "Slot number #{slot_number} is now free."
        slot_number = slot_number - 1
        parking_lot.delete_at(slot_number)
        parking_lot[slot_number]
        #puts parking_lot
    when input[0] = "quit"
      break
    when input[0] = "status"
      if parking_lot.count == 0
        puts "No cars are parked."
      else
      puts "Slot No. Registration No. Color"
      parking.sort!
      i = 0
      y = ""
      while i < allocated_slot.to_i do
          x = parking_lot[i].to_s
          y = x.split(' ')
          puts "#{y[0]} #{y[1]} #{y[2]}" #
          #y.each { |a| print a, " " }
          i = i+1
        end
     end
    when input[0] = "registration_numbers_for_cars_with_color"
      puts "registration number for cars"
    when input[0] = "slot_numbers_for_cars_with_color"
      puts "slot number for cars with color"
    when input[0] = "slot_number_for_registration_number"
      puts "slot number for registration number"
    when input[0] = "check"
      puts parking_lot
    else
    puts "Command Error"
    end
  end
```

and the output goes like this:
[1, "HA-312424242", "Green"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array being outputted that looks like this:

```
[1, "HA-312424242", "Green"]
```

Then you can call the `join` method on it like this:

```
 [1, "HA-312424242", "Green"].join(' ')
```

and it will produce:

```
"1 HA-312424242 Green"
```

Comment: Hi this really works but now I have another problem since the output goes like this "1 HA-312424242 Green" "2 HA-312342323-323 Black" "3 HA-323232-12132 Red" how can i shift the next outputs to the next line through my array.. Thank you Mark!

Comment: can you just type `puts [1, "HA-312424242", "Green"].join(' ')`?

Comment: I can't because i'm getting the input from the user this is my code now   puts "Slot No. Registration No. Color"
      parking.sort!
      puts parking_lot.join(' ')   and every time the user input a new car info the output goes horizontally in which i want every output to be on the next line. anyways Thank you! :)

Comment: Well, you could just write `puts` all by itself which will simply print a newline character which is what you want.